# Why does SourceTree mac version show such a messy branch tree graph for merge?

Tags: git, git-branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I have 2 branches v5 & v4 and what I did was to merge v4 into v5 at certain points of time. It is a straightforward process. The Sourcetree window version shows that clearly, the blue line at leftmost is v5 branch, the red line next to it is v4 and take commit [93ed2a5] `Merge branch 'v4' into v5` as an example. Its merge base is `5378fca1fb` on v5 and `97c1be8b1f` on v4.

[image: sourcetree win graph]

But to my surprise, SourceTree mac version (3.x & 4.x) shows a rather messy branch tree graph! At first I have no idea where those lines came from and why so many of them!

[image: sourcetree mac graph]

Then I check each line's endpoints and found each line represents a merge from v4 to v5. But I have no idea why sourcetree will draw the line like that!

I also try [tower](https://www.git-tower.com/mac), tower can also show the branch tree graph correctly (just 2 lines most of times). The graph in tower look similar to sourcetree win version

[image: tower graph]

**Strangely** I find [fork](https://git-fork.com/) has the same problem as sourcetree mac (e.g. check the merge commits 93ed2a5 & b8fc27e). So I suspect there may be a hidden git problem triggers sourcetree and fork to show such a messy graph.

[image: fork]

Any idea?

One comment reminds me to check whether these graphs are topologically identical. But from what I see they are not. For example, the v5 branch is always the leftmost line and the v4 line is always the 2nd leftmost line in all the graphs. I don't think these graphs are topologically identical.

Comment: As noted on Ask Different we need motre information. Where do those unrecognised lines merge to . Scroll to the top of the macOS Window and show where they merge into master or what is the name of their branch

Comment: But I said there (I have deleted the question there per your suggestion) and here, each line represents a merge from v4 to v5. Each line has an end point at v5 and an end point at v4. I gave a example for the commit [93ed2a5]

Comment: I know what you think they are - however Sourcetree thinks differently and we do not have enough information to see what sourcetree thinks is happening

Comment: But why does sourcetree win  version show it correctly then? I just don't know what other information I can provide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git log graph differs in IntelliJ and VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65855361/git-log-graph-differs-in-intellij-and-vscode) Basically there's just more than one way to draw a "map" of the same topology. There is no "correctly" - there is simply what you happen to like better. Keep in mind that when a line (branch history) is rising vertically, if it has not been merged, it can be shown at any height/length; it's simply a matter of _in what order_ we list the commits.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so, in that question the 2 graph were topologically identical, but this is not my case. My case here, the v5 branch is always the leftmost line and so many lines created by merge is not topologically identical to the window version and tower version.

Comment: @matt I updated my question to explain why I think they were not topologically identical. But thanking for the comment.

Comment: Well I'm saying they are topologically identical. Remember in topology a donut and a coffee cup are indistinguishable.

Comment: For example in Sourcetree if you change the commit sort order you'll get very different results. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eN5f.png But I assure you it is the same acyclic graph.

Comment: @matt Now I see it! You were right. After I change to the commit sort order to date order, they look alike. My problem here is in the mac version is the ancestor order. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234094/discussion-between-qiulang-and-matt).

Answer (score 1):

The reason I saw different graphs in sourcetree window version and mac version was because I used **date order** in win version and **ancestor order** in mac version. As @matt's comment said they were **topologically identical**. It might not be easy to see that but if I turn all those lines from right to left (imaging turning them around) the graphs then indeed looks alike.

Having said that I have to say **ancestor order** graph is rather messy and unreadable. I rather prefer tower's graph.

Besides, sourcetree mac version has an obvious bug for **date order** as long as I can remembered. If I rebase a commit A to be the parents of commit B even though commit A is later than commit B, with date order the mac version can't show graph correctly,  refer to the following pictures,

The commit 00643fa was rebased to be the parents of 440f371. But mac version can't show them in one line.

[image: date order in mac]

The window version shows them correctly.

[image: date order in win]